# Call a function through a variable in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a game engine in Python as a "weekend project" but I have a problem.

I'm trying to make it that a user can declare a keybind by typing the key and the function into a text file what they want to run but when I run the code from that sheet with exec it runs the function and I have no idea on how to call the function through the variable. (Also I don't want it to run the function when it runs the code.)

Here is the code I use for executing the code from binds.zdata

```
for line in bind:
    try:
        exec line
    except:
        try:
            error.write(localtime + " : " + "ERROR: Could not bind key from the bind file : " + line)
        except:
            pass
```

Here's the text in binds.zdata

```
_w = Functions.motion.move().forward()
_a = Functions.motion.move().left()
_s = Functions.motion.move().back()
_d = Functions.motion.move().right()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to lose the `()` at the end of each line:

```
_w = Functions.motion.move().forward
_a = Functions.motion.move().left
_s = Functions.motion.move().back
_d = Functions.motion.move().right
```

now you can call the function through the variable by simply applying parenthesis, such as:

```
_w()
```

Comment: Players can use this to cheat, FYI, since through this functionality they could use introspection and expose your entire program's object model and use it however they want. Or even re-write parts of it. If they can figure out where you save the score, for example, they could add code to give them a winning score.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure I recommend "exec" since somebody could put **any** code in there.

But here is your problem.
`_w = Functions.motion.move().forward()`
Calls the function 'forward' and puts the results in _w.
`_w = Functions.motion.move().forward`
Assigns the function 'forward' to the variable '_w'.

Since you asked what I would do, I would create a set of tokens that represent the various functions and then let them do the mapping in side a config file (see: ConfigParser). Then parse the config file. It is a little more work, but a lot more secure.

Comment: How would you suggest I should use to run the code? @RobertB

Answer (score 3):

I'd first change the lines in the binds.zdata file like this so they assign a function to each of the variables:

```
_w = Functions.motion.move().forward
_a = Functions.motion.move().left
_s = Functions.motion.move().back
_d = Functions.motion.move().right
```

Then, assuming that `Functions` is defined, I'd execute all the lines in the file at once with something like:

```
try:
    execfile('binds.zdata')
except Exception as exc:
    error.write(localtime + " : " + "ERROR: executing binds file")
```

Afterwards, the `_w`, `_a`, `_s`, `_d` variables will have the desired function assigned to them, which you can call as usual — i.e. `_w()`, `_a()`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Reading the config like that with exec is going to open you to all kinds of pain at runtime, as the user's config file is going to be executable code that you are just trusting.   Malicious or unintentionally just bad commands will get execute.  You could template it like this:

```
def read_config(config_file):

    user_button_map = {}
    with open(config_file, 'r') as fh:
        for line in fh.readlines():
            key,func_key = line.strip().split(',')                

            assert(key in BUTTON_MAP_FUNCTIONS),"no such action"
            user_button_map[key] = BUTTON_MAP_FUNCTIONS[func_key]

    return user_button_map


BUTTON_MAP_FUNCTIONS = {
   "forward" : Functions.motion.move().forward,
   "left" : Functions.motion.move().left,
   # etc...
}

# sample config file
# w, forward
# a, left
# etc...
```

Comment: Similar to my idea, I would improve this by checking out ConfigParser.

Comment: agreed, configparser or another config management tool would be good here too